# Remove div if no img

Tags: jquery, events

I have a script which can retrieve url and favicon: [MyWebsite](http://moskah.nl/)

If you click on the 'share' button with textarea blank you will see it places a blank item. How do I write in Jquery: if the item has no text/html, hide/remove item? I have tried this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

     if ($('.item').text('')) {
        $(this).hide();

    }
});
```

It doesn't work. I have also tried other stuff and also on window load, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shareButton').click( function() {
         if ($('#myInput').val()) {
            // Add new row here
         }
    });
});
```

You should not add a row, if the input is empty. So, instead of hiding the new row, you should not add it. You should add it if there is some text.

Comment: Thanks "instead of hiding the new row, you should not add it" Good one:)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if id_status length == 0, do nothing. Else, post it normally

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_submit").click(function() {
        if( $("#id_status").val().length == 0)
            return false;
        else {
            // do your magic 
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check all items so try this structure

```
$('.item').each(function(indx){
   if($(this).html()=="")
    {
       $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

may be you need to use $.trim() to be sure that inside html does not have blank space